# Getting a socketio client connection to receive a "signal only works in main thread" error

Tags: python, django, websocket, socket.io

So, I am trying to make my django app automatically connect to socketio client when some conditions happen and parse data from it in order to thereafter send it to my own web socket and show on web page.
When I'm using this code:

**views.py**

```
def match(request, match_id):
    match = get_object_or_404(Match, pk=match_id)
    context = {'match': match}
    if match.is_live:
        livescore = Livescore(match.match_id, ).socket()
        context.setdefault('livescore', livescore)
    return render(request, 'myapp/match.html', context)
```

to create this class' object:

```
class Livescore:
    def __init__(
        self, list_id=None, scoreboard_callback=None, event_callback=None
):
        self.list_id = list_id
        self.sb_callback = scoreboard_callback
        self.event_callback = event_callback

    def socket(self):
        sio = socketio.Client()

        @sio.event
        def connect():
            print("connection established")
            ready_data = {"listId": self.list_id}

            sio.emit("readyForMatch", json.dumps(ready_data))

        @sio.event
        def log(data):
            # do stuff

        @sio.event
        def event(data):
            # do stuff


        @sio.event
        def disconnect():
            print("disconnected from server")

        sio.connect("<websocket URI im trying to connect to for data parsing>")

        return sio
```

and parse info with callbacks, I receive this error:

> ValueError: signal only works in main thread

After I figure out this problem (if I do) I want to put this code into my django-cron class which will every time check whether the condition has been fulfilled, connect to socketio and store its instance somewhere else to operate with info I'm receiving and put it into my own web socket.

Is there any way I can resolve this error I'm getting?